# JS onload - controllist - nodownload for multiple videos in chrome (only working on first vide)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, google-chrome

On a wordpress site, trying to load some vidoes, They are copyrighted 
and did not want users to just download them.

The methods applied all work in various browsers, But chrome has added a feature that allows you to download html5 videos and embeds the buttons to the video its playing

You can disable this, by using the controlist = nodownload.

Each page may contain about 20 videos, and the person who is creating and updating the videos is not savvy on html, so manually adding the html is not really an option.

Someone suggested using JS to set the controlslist and this appears to work, but only for the first video in the page. 
All other videos show the download icon, I have no idea why its only working for first video loaded.

```
<script> window.onload = function() { video = document.querySelector('video'); if (video) { video.setAttribute("controlsList", "nodownload"); } }; </script>
```

Another workaround is hiding the buttons using CSS, But this is not the best method and still can be clickable. I like the JS version as its clean. Can anyone see why this may only work for the first video only?

the CSS Method is:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    overflow: hidden !important
}
video::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
    display:none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    width: calc(100% + 32px);
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Example: 
[image: First Video works]
[image: All other fail and show download link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var noDownload = function() {
    var videoElem = document.getElementsByTagName("VIDEO");
    for (x in videoElem) {
       if (isNaN(x) == true) {
            continue;
        }
       videoElem[x].setAttribute("controlsList", "nodownload");
    }
}
noDownload();
```

```css
video {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video controls>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video controls>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video controls>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t5g78cje/

All you need here is the javascript code, I call on the function globally because thats how I got the function to run in JsFiddle, but you can use window.onload if you prefer.

And if youd like to know the reason your code was only changing the first video, its because the querySelectors will return the first element in the DOM it finds, and you were adding the attribute to that only. In the answer, videoElem is an array with all the video elements, I loop through the array and add the attribute to each item

Comment: I give this a test and unfortunately it didn't work, I added two images to the first post showing the no download link and the second video with a download link

Comment: I gave you an example. With this one I tested it and it worked for me

Comment: Also, just to let you know it is not possible to stop people from getting these videos. This just stops them using this particular button to get them.

Comment: The revised snippet worked perfectly thanks.am also aware it doesn't stop it. I was just trying to not make it so simple. 9/10 of users can just about manage to login, so viewing source I ain't worried about. Just right clicking on video and selecting download and the download icon I just wanted to remove, that I had no idea chrome added